# Can I install keytool without the whole bunch of Java JDK?

Tags: java

I don't want to install the robust Java JDK with gigabytes of installation data with an all time java updater which is eating my memory and annoying as hell, **I just need the keytool.**

Is there **any option to obtain keytool program with minimal software excess?**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You may use an alternative to keytool.

For example : [KeyStore Explorer](http://keystore-explorer.org/).

[image]